# Transport Optimization (PuLP) with Shipping Volume Discount

Tags: python, optimization, linear-programming, pulp

In the transport optimization problem of PuLP, i am want to optimize the final cost after taking into consideration volume based cost discount. Hence in the problem below we have 3 warehouses and  3 projects with each projects having a demand and warehouse having supply with cost of transport defined.

```
# Creates a list of all the supply nodes
warehouses = ["A", "B", "C"]

# Creates a dictionary for the number of units of supply for each supply node
supply = {"A": 150, "B": 600, "C":1000}

# Creates a list of all demand nodes
projects = ["1", "2", "3"]

# Creates a dictionary for the number of units of demand for each demand node
demand = {
    "1": 150,
    "2": 450,
    "3": 900,
}

# Creates a list of costs of each transportation path
costs = [  # Projects
    [5,1,9],  # A   warehouses
    [4,2,8],  # B
    [8,7,2]   # C
]

# The cost data is made into a dictionary
costs = makeDict([warehouses, projects], costs, 0)

# Import PuLP modeler functions
from pulp import *

# Creates the 'prob' variable to contain the problem data
prob = LpProblem("Material Supply Problem", LpMinimize)

# Creates a list of tuples containing all the possible routes for transport
Routes = [(w, b) for w in warehouses for b in projects]

# A dictionary called 'Vars' is created to contain the referenced variables(the routes)
vars = LpVariable.dicts("Route", (warehouses, projects), 0, None, LpInteger)
```

At this stage usually the objective function is created as below

```
# The objective function is added to 'prob' first
prob += (
    lpSum([vars[w][j] * costs[w][j] for (w, j) in assign]),
    "Sum_of_Assignment_Costs",
)
```

Instead of this I am trying to figure out how to incorporate volume based discount into objective function such as if Warehouse C fulfills >= 600 units then transport cost will be 10% discounted per unit, if Warehouse B fulfills >= 200 units then transport cost will be 5% discounted per unit

Comment: The [PuLP](https://coin-or.github.io/pulp)
OR library from [COIN](https://coin-or.org) is focused on linear programming.
But you seem to be describing a non-linear (perhaps a piecewise linear) problem. Would you care to cast it in different terms? Is there a [MIP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_programming) aspect you'd like to highlight? Are you looking for other software packages that would be a better fit for your use case?

Comment: There are a couple ways to accomplish this.  This is a nice suggestion:  https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/4075/how-to-write-quantity-discount-constraint

Comment: @J_h not restricted to linear programming, open to explore other opensource solvers such as gurobi as well. I want to understand programmatically how to approach this problem.

Comment: PuLP can also be used fairly effectively for moderate sized MILP problems. The formulation approach linked above on or.stackexchange could be implemented in pulp with some minor modifications to your model.

Comment: Any reference articles on how to implement programmatically would help !